# Трассировка лучей на GLSL

Tags: opengl

Как осуществить трассировку лучей в шейдере? Проблема в том, что многие алгоритмы трассировки лучей предназначены для выполнения на процессоре, в то же время полезной информации об осуществлении их на GPU не так уж много. Насколько мне известны принципы работы трассировки, луч исходящий от камеры вглубь экрана проверяется на пересечение с объектами сцены, и если такое пересечение обнаружено – рисуется цвет пикселя того объекта, с которым собственно и произошло пересечение луча. В противном случае пиксель остаётся цветом фона. Далее идёт второй луч, и алгоритм повторяется вновь. Как осуществить всё это на GPU? Каким образом изображаются объекты сцены на экране? Как скажем, например, изобразить стандартную сферу?

Comment: А в чём, собственно, существенное отличие от аналогичной реализации на CPU?

Answer (score 1):

А смысл в такой трассировке? На сколько я знаю, трассировку применяют для отрисовки поверхностей, искажающие и/или рассеивающие лучи света (стекла, полупрозрачные поверхности, короче для моделирования сложного поведения световых лучей) или же для изображения гладких аналитических поверхностей (да здравствует матан и аналит. геометрия). Для таких простых случаев трассировка будет ресурсоемка.

ЗЫ В одной статейке о трассировке на GLSL (не помню автора и не помню назавание) описывался метод, для отрисовки тканей человеческого тела. Автор статьи пишет рендерер для томографов МРТ. Он рассказывал, что тамограф предоставляет ему 3D текстуру (ака воксельная графика) с объектом. В этой текстуре каждый воксель содержит инфу о плотности ткани (кость, мясо, кожа и т.д.). Далее он передает эту текстуру фрагментному шейдеру, и там уже пускает лучи. Если подробнее: он брал плоскость (обычный QUAD) и рисовал её с вкюченным фрагментым шейдером перед экраном. Далее, когда рисовался очередной пиксель этого квада, он брал радиус-вектор пиксела и вдоль него пускал луч. Дальше он проверял каждый воксель 3D текстуры на пересечение с лучём. Но проверял по слоям, от ближнего к дальнему. Так он смог добиться полупрозрачности мягких тканей.